# Merging two Google accounts

Tags: google-account, migrate-data

I currently have two "general" Google accounts. I set up the first several years ago to use stuff like Calendar, Contacts and also Analytics. I didn't want to use it for e-mail, as I already have an e-mail address and I didn't want to migrate everything to Google. So I used just some "random" user name like user87142 for it. Recently, I set up a second account to use it for a project on Google Code, as I wanted to have some meaningful user name there. After a while, I started using this account for other purposes, like signing up on Github, Discourse and also added it as another login option here on Stackexchage.

Well, now I have the problem, that I have two "active" accounts, which gets quite confusing. Sometimes, I have to log in using the other account to check something (for example, Analytics), then I have to go back to the other to sign up for some website. I know you can log in with multiple accounts on Google, but I'd rather have just a single account. And I don't really want to loose my calendars and contacts or have to set up Analytics again.

According to [Google's Help pages](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304), it is not possible (yet?) to merge two accounts directly. However, if you search for this topic, there seems to be a tool called ['Google Takeout'](https://www.google.com/takeout/) for merging two **Google+** accounts.

**Now my question:** is it possible to use that tool for merging two 'normal' Google accounts too? If yes, what are the steps you have to perform, what things could go wrong? If no, is there some other way of 'merging' my accounts?

Comment: Regarding the migration to webapps.SE: I don't really know why this site even exits... webapps.SE and superuser.SE both claim to be about "power users". If something is web-based or not seems a bit arbitrary, especially in those days, where the line between them is getting blurred more and more. But as long as I get answers, I don't really care :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual Answer: No.

Close but slightly off answer:

The closest thing to merging accounts at this time is linking multiple accounts. There is a nice article linked below, but the basic steps are:

1. Navigate to google.com/accounts and sign in with what you want to be your primary account
2. Personal Settings -> Multiple Sign-In -> save
3. At the top where your email address is displayed, select the drop down menu and select Sign in to Other Account
4. You will be able to switch between them quickly once this is complete.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25008/access-all-your-google-accounts-at-the-same-time-with-multiple-sign-in/

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I already feared. I don't really like the multiple sign in method. I now manually exported (almost) everything from my old account and imported it into my new account. Luckily, for Analytics, you can actually just ["hand over" the profiles](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/lz_gVxtupkM).